# How to move multiple child items to parent level

Tags: jquery

I have divs which contains two input fields inside of a label, all I want to do is move second input field to outside of that label.
here is whats that first:

```
<div id="divQ_1" class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 form-group checkbox">
  <label>
    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The isChecked field is required." id="checks_1__isChecked" name="checks[1].isChecked" type="checkbox" value="true">
    <input name="checks[1].isChecked" type="hidden" value="false">               
  </label>
</div>
```

should loook like this:

```
<div id="divQ_1" class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 form-group checkbox">
  <label>
    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The isChecked field is required." id="checks_1__isChecked" name="checks[1].isChecked" type="checkbox" value="true">              
  </label>
  <input name="checks[1].isChecked" type="hidden" value="false"> 
</div>
```

this is what I did but cant place the input there;

```
var count = 0;
$('input[type="hidden"]').each(function () {
  $(this).detach().append("#divQ_" + count);
  count++;
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) to move all the hidden inputs after its parent label element.

```
$('input[type="hidden"]').each(function(){
  $(this).parent("label").after(this);
});
```

Comment: or simply `.after(this)` ... don't really need a new jQ object

Answer (score 0):

try the following, it should work

```
$('input[type="hidden"]').each(function () {
    $("#divQ_1").append($(this).clone());
    $(this).detach();
})
```